# Why can't I display attachment_image_src with Custom Size?

Tags: shortcode, images

I'm trying to display an attachment with a custom size that I created with `add_image_size` called "custom-size-01"

What the code returns is the word "Array"

I've looked at the wordpress reference and been trying the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` reference and tried the example code it gives but i haven't been able to make it work.

I haven't figured out what I'm doing wrong and could use any input to show me where I'm making a mistake.

```
if($imageid){
 echo "<img src=\"";
 echo  wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageid, 'custom-size-01', false); 
 echo "\" width=\"100%\" >"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With wp_get_attachment_image_src  you get a array with values corresponding to the (0) url, (1) width, (2) height, and (3) scale of an image attachment (from the wordpress doc).

you code can be:

```
if($imageid){
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageid, 'custom-size-01', false);
 echo "<img src=\"";
 echo $image_attributes[0];  
 echo "\" width=\"100%\" >"; 
 }
```